# Why is my NSArray iterating according to the number of NSDictonaries

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

This is an odd issue, and I've been working on trying different work arounds/bug fixing. But I've spent a considerable amount of time on this and hope someone with some fresh eyes can potentially spot the root cause of this issue.

Basically I am serializing a JSON file as an NSArray. I need to do some manipulation with this data, so I create an NSMutableArray of that original NSArray.

I then create a NSDictonary, and compare objectForKey's.

However, I noticed when I output through an NSLog statement in the Xcode console, I see the Array is iterated by the number of dictionaries. Why is this printing out 30 arrays each with 30 dictionaries?

Here is some some code that I have that is related to this issue. Let me know what your thoughts are and what I can do to improve on this/fix.

```
    self.objectsList = [[NSArray alloc] init];

[[HTTPServices instance] getConnectabilityObject:^(NSArray * _Nullable dataArray, NSString * _Nullable errorMessage) {
    if (dataArray) {
        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        for (NSDictionary *dictonary in dataArray) {
            ConnectabilityObject *object = [[ConnectabilityObject alloc] init];
            object.ConnectabilityTitle = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectTitle"];
            object.ConnectabilityObjectType  = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectType"];
            object.ConnectabilityFullIPAddress = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectFullIPAddress"];
            object.ConnectabilityObjectLastOctet = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectLastOctet"];
            object.ConnectabilityObjectPortNumberOne = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectPortNum1"];
            object.ConnectabilityObjectPortNumberTwo = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectPortNum2"];
            object.ConnectabilityObjectPortNumberThree = [dictonary objectForKey:@"ConnectabilityObjectPortNum3"];

            [array addObject:object];
        }
        self.objectsList = array;
    }
}];
```

**UPDATE**

Here is the NSLogStatement that associates with this array. Please note that I'm logging this data from another method. This method is found below.

```
-(void)pingResult:(NSNumber*)success {
    NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_objectlist];
    for (NSDictionary *objectDictonary in objects) {
        self.objectlist = nil;
        NSLog(@"Another Method NSLog %@", objects);
    }
```

}

Here is the NSLog from the Console. Please note that this "Another Method NSLog" is called 30 times which is equal to the number of ConnectabilityObjects found in the JSON file.

```
    2016-06-14 11:28:55.724 FlightPath[3866:1176806] Another Method NSLog (
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16695d80>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696ad0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696b90>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696be0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696c30>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696ca0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696cf0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b14e0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1530>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b15c0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1610>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1660>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b16b0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1700>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1750>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b17a0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b17f0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b18b0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1900>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696d20>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696d50>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696da0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696df0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696e40>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696e90>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696ee0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696f30>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696f80>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696fd0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x166970e0>"
)
2016-06-14 11:28:55.729 FlightPath[3866:1176806] Another Method NSLog (
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16695d80>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696ad0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696b90>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696be0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696c30>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696ca0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696cf0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b14e0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1530>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b15c0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1610>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1660>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b16b0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1700>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1750>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b17a0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b17f0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b18b0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x165b1900>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696d20>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696d50>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696da0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696df0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696e40>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696e90>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696ee0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696f30>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696f80>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x16696fd0>",
    "<ConnectabilityObject: 0x166970e0>"
)
```

Comment: It's unclear. You have a `for loop` and your code shouldn't compile, you do `[array addObject:object];` where `object` is not declared.

Comment: A question about surprising NSLog output ought to contain at least one NSLog statement.

Comment: Make sure you don't already have a variable named `object`, like @Larme said, `[array addObject:object]` shouldn't compile based on this code because your `ConnectabilityObject *object` won't be in scope at that point.

Comment: My apologies, I edited the code slightly when I posted this into stack overflow. I've updated the existing question code with the proper code.

Comment: I'll get a NSLog statement here in a moment for you.

Comment: If that log function is accurate, then you're printing out the entire objects array rather than just a single dictionary.

Comment: Right, but why would the array be printed 30x's which is the equal amount to the dictionary. Yes I can print just the dictionary, but the issue at large is the array is iterated by the same number of dictionaries.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're expecting?  You add (presuambly) 30 `ConnectabilityObject`s into `objectsList`.  Then, you make an `NSMutableArray *objects` with the values in `objectsList`.  Next, iterate through `objects` (30 executions) and log the value of `objects`, which would print all of the values in the array 30 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup.  It's an NSLog mistake...

```
-(void)pingResult:(NSNumber*)success {
    for (NSDictionary *objectDictonary in _objectlist) {
        NSLog(@"%@", objectDictonary);
    }
}
```

In the first attempt, the OP code was doing this:

```
NSMutableArray *objects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_objectlist];
```

... which needlessly copied the instance array var.

And the OP code was doing this:

```
self.objectlist = nil;
```

... which dangerously deletes the instance array that you're trying to inspect.

And, generating confusing output, the OP code was doing this:

```
NSLog(@"Another Method NSLog %@", objects);
```

... which says: "for each element in my array, log my entire array".

Comment: Thank you! You've sparked my thought process, you were right I was logging this wrong. I've marked your answer as correct and upvoted. Thank you again!!